Gnome: How to save images with "Enter" instead of clicking "Save"?
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, with Gnome (42.9),and for some reason i can't save images from the browser by pressing "Enter", instead I have to click the "Save" button with the mouse. This happens with multiple browsers.
I'm avoiding changing to KDE. Is there a way to change this with GNOME?

works for me in 22.04.5 with wayland and GNOME 42.9 I press Print Scrn whilst Selection is highlighted and voila! will also work with the other options selected
